# Feign client is not working with Cloud gateway? throwing exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

Building a simple microservice using Spring Boot version 3.1.3, which has two services one is api-gateway and another fisherman-service. API-Gateway is using cloud-gateway, eureka-cient and openfeign and the fisherman-service is a spring boot application that has exposed certain REST endpoins. While trying to access fisherman-service via feign-client service, getting exception.

**pom.xml - Feign Client**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.techverse</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-gateway-with-feign-and-eureka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api-gateway-with-feign-and-eureka</name>
    <description>api-gateway-with-feign-and-eureka</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.yml file: Feign Client**

```
server:
  port: 8089
  
spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway-3
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

**appication file: Feign-Client**

```
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ApiGatewayWithFeignAndEurekaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayWithFeignAndEurekaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Feign-Client interface**

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@FeignClient(name = "FISHERMAN-SERVICE")
public interface FishermanClient {

    @GetMapping("fm/msg")
    String msg();
}
```

**Feign-Client controller class**

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/feign")
@RestController
public class FismermanCallingController {

    @Autowired
    private FishermanClient fishermanClient;

    @GetMapping("/msg")
    public String msg(){
        String msg = fishermanClient.msg();
        return msg;
    }
}
```

**Fisherman Service Controller Class:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/fm")
public class FishermanController {

    private FishermanService fishermanService;

    @Autowired
    FishermanController(FishermanService fishermanService) {
        this.fishermanService = fishermanService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/msg")
    public String msg(){
        return "Hello from Fisherman Service";
    }
}
```

The fisherman service is up and running on the port 8082 and gives proper response while hitting the uri from postman or chrome.

> **URI:** localhost:8082/fm/msg

> **Response:** Hello from Fisherman Service

But when we try to access the same via feign client we get an exception.

> **URI:** localhost:8089/feign/msg

**Exception:**

```
2023-09-02T20:56:56.287+05:30 ERROR 7944 --- [ctor-http-nio-7] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [72f710ac-3]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/feign/msg"

java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-7
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/feign/msg" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1712) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.blocking.client.BlockingLoadBalancerClient.choose(BlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:163) ~[spring-cloud-loadbalancer-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.loadbalancer.FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.execute(FeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.java:118) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:100) ~[feign-core-12.4.jar:na]
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:70) ~[feign-core-12.4.jar:na]
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:96) ~[feign-core-12.4.jar:na]
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy109.msg(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.techverse.apigatewaywithfeignandeureka.controllers.FismermanCallingController.msg(FismermanCallingController.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:145) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.9.jar:3.5.9]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer$HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServer.java:1052) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:710) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at reactor.netty.transport.ServerTransport$ChildObserver.onStateChange(ServerTransport.java:481) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:647) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:114) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:238) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) ~[netty-codec-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:4.1.97.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

And the fisherman-service is correctly registered at Eureka server with name "**FISHERMAN-SERVICE**"

Answer (score 0):

Springgateway use the WebFlux

Three methods can solve this problem

1. use a thread to call feign

```
@GetMapping("/msg")
public Mono<String> msg(){
    Future futer = //some thread to call fishermanClient.msg();   
    return Mono.just(futer.get());
}
```

2. change fegin to webclient

```
@GetMapping("/msg")
public Mono<String> msg(){
    Mono<String> msg = webclient.....();
    return msg;
}
```

3. use https://github.com/PlaytikaOSS/feign-reactive instead of feign

Answer (score 0):

As @zt9788 rightly points out, combining WebFlux-based Spring Cloud Gateway with blocking Feign, will cause issues.

The Spring team recommends [Spring Interface Clients](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/rest-clients.html#rest-http-interface) as a non-blocking alternative to Spring Cloud OpenFeign.

Alternatively, the [MVC version of Spring Cloud Gateway](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/pull/2949#issue-1703012276) is now in the works, but you should probably wait for `4.1.0` release (end of 2023) to use it in production.